# DefaultMutableTreeNode icon

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JTree` displayed in a `JContentPane` built from `DefaultMutableTreeNode` objects. The tree is intented to display the local file-system. The data should be loaded on request, therefore when the user wants to expand it. This works well, but as long as there are no child items in the node, it displays a file-icon, and turns into a folder-icon when child items have been inserted.

How can I make the node display a folder-icon always, although there are (yet) no child items?

Comment: See also [*File Browser GUI*](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692).

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement cell renderer for your tree. So you can define icon for the node.
[See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) the sample for a table (tree also has method `setCellRenderer`)

Comment: only as a very last measure: if you all you  need is to distinguish folders from files, simply use the ask/allowsChildren properties (assuming a DefaultTreeModel)

Comment: Thank you for hint. I've never used these properties before (always via renderer).

Answer (score 1):

Using a DefaultMutableTreeNode (or a custom implementation of TreeNode), the means to distinguish *files* from *empty folders* is its allowsChildren property:

```
// get a list of files
File[] files = new File(".").listFiles();
// configure the nodes' allowsChildren as the isDir of the File object
for (File file : files) {
    root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file, file.isDirectory()));
}          
// configure the TreeModel to use nodes' allowsChildren property to
// decide on its leaf-ness
DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode ();
DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel (root);
tree = new JTree (treeModel);
addFiles (root);                            // build the catalog tree recursively
treeModel.setAsksAllowsChildren (true);     // allows empty nodes to appear as folders
```

with

```
if (file.isDirectory ())
  newNode.setAllowsChildren (true);
```

in the addFiles() routine. The setAsksAllowsChildren(true) needs to come after the tree is built.